# The Lodash Install In Webpack Guides page

Tags: javascript, webpack, lodash

When I look [this](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#creating-a-bundle) page they use `npm install --save lodash` to install lodash. But when I look [this](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#npm-scripts) page, the package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  ===> "devDependencies": { <===
    "webpack": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5" <- ???
  }
}
```

Am I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No need to get confused. It's pretty simple.
>
> use below command if you need to `lodash` in the production

```
npm install lodash --save
```

> use below command if you don't need to `lodash` in the production

```
npm install lodash --save-dev
```

> Once you are done. lodash's functions will be available globally. If you get any error like `_ is not defined.` Then you can `import` lodash like this

```
import _ from 'lodash'; OR let _ = require('lodash')
```